# please refer links for CSS and other simple styling ways used with Visual Studio c#

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, styling

yes can search google but there are thousand of results

by your experience which links give the best for a beginner who has to make some website using it within a month.

- i mean the styling,
- the ways to style the footer (you knw the copyright message)

using vs08 c# aspx

Comment: Not sure what more of an answer you are looking for than: yes, HTML+CSS...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, when you are beginning to use CSS you understand that browser compatibility is the main point. You can't only referer to CSS2 or CSS3 convention. 
Take a look at [quirkmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html).

Then here come [HTML Dog](http://htmldog.com/guides/).

[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/) is good for beginners but you'll quickly need more pro and detailed references. And at this point, it will depend on your needs.

Then you have to know some CSS tricks & hacks : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500827/css-tips-which-every-beginning-developer-should-know-about. 
[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) is really our savior.

@media screen
{
    div p.goodLuck:before 
    {
    content: "Good luck !"  // Don't work on IE (owwww noz, first compatiblity fail :D)
    }
}